# Who insures reinsurers? Is there an "insurer of last resort"?

Tags: insurance

Assume a massive natural disaster occurred, at a scale such that "front-line" insurance companies (e.g. State Farm) had to turn to their re-insurers (e.g. Swiss Re).

What if the re-insurers became overwhelmed? Who insures *them*? Is there such a thing as a re-re-insurer?

At the end of the chain, if everyone runs out of money, who reimburses the policyholder? Do they just lose out, or do governments step in?

Comment: I imagine this is country-dependant. In Spain the last resort insurer is the [Consorcio de Compensación de Seguros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insurance_Compensation_Consortium).